# iOS constraints doesn't allow to use multiplier

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am trying to layout some custom views and when I try to activate the constraints, Xcode says that I can't use multiplier. Here is an example of the code:

```
class MenuView: UIView {

    var addButton: AddButton!
    var settingsButton: SettingsButton!

    // ........

    func setConstraints (withBarReference reference: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) {
        NSLayoutConstraints.activateConstraints([
             // ........
             addButton.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.centerXAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
             // ........
             settingsButton.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.centerXAnchor, multiplier: 1.5)
        ])
    }

}
```

The thing here is that Xcode gives a syntax error on the contraintEqualToAnchor: functions and says that I should replace "multiplier" to "constant".

Why can't I use the multiplier option with the X center anchors?

Comment: If your constraints already exists, then you can't change their "multiplier" parameter, you can only change "constant"

Comment: Didn’t you miss the .isActive = true ?

Answer (score 32):

You can't set multiplier using helper functions, but you can set multiplier using NSLayoutConstraint initializer. Just got stuck by this myself, but found the answer.

Your code: `addButton.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.centerXAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)`

Correct code: `NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)`

Also, don't forget to activate this constraint by typing `isActive = true`

Answer (score 4):

Previous answers work very weird now.

You can simply create `UILayoutGuide` with multiplier width/height with view and set `guide.trailing` equal to the `centerX` of your subview.

For example, if you need to place the addButton in the first 1/3 of a view and settingsButton in 2/3 you can simply set two layout guides

```
let addButtonGuide = UILayoutGuide()
self.addLayoutGuide(addButtonGuide)
addButtonGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).isActive = true
addButtonGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
addButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addButtonGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

// same for settingsButton but using 2/3 for the multiplier
```

But the really best way is to use `UIStackView` and set its `distribution` property to `equalCentering`.

Another option is to use uncommon Auto Layout API to create `NSLayoutDimension` between two `centerXAnchor`s and make constraint to `self.widthAnchor`:

```
addButton.centerXAnchor.anchorWithOffset(to: self.centerXAnchor)
    .constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.25).isActive = true

self.centerXAnchor.anchorWithOffset(to: settingsButton.centerXAnchor)
    .constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.25).isActive = true
```

Comment: UILayoutGuide is exactly what I was looking for, you just made my day sir!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that in IB you can use the multiplier option with Center X and obtain the effect you're looking for (set the center of button1 at 1/4 the width of the view it's in, and the center of button2 at 2/3 of the width of the view it's in):
                    [image: setting the center of a button at 1/4 the width of the view it's in, using the Interface Builder]. [image: setting the center of a button at 2/3 the width of the view it's in, in StoryBoard]

I tried to use it both in code and in IB, and in code I got the same error as you.
Surprisingly, in IB it worked, no errors, no warnings. (I am using Xcode 7, will try it in Xcode 8 to see if it still works).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multipliers on `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` anchors - multiplying by a position along a line doesn't make sense in a way that the constraints system can understand. You can only use multipliers with `NSLayoutDimension` anchors, which measure *lengths*, like the width.

The layout you are trying to make would be better achieved using a stack view.

Comment: IB allows you to do this even though it "doesn't make sense". It actually does and sometimes it's the most efficient way to achieve the result. For example to align view's left side to quarter line of parent view. That would be view.leftAnchor constrainted to superview.centerX with 0.5 multiplier or 1.5 for 3rd quarter line. Without this, you would have to create invisible views only used for guide snapping. See my answer below on how to do this via code :)